# PRISM + Splat as IOC

Tags: prism, reactiveui

I have previously used DryIOC as my IOC before, but I would like to try Splat for my IOC, would it be possible to combine these two?

I have tried making a `LoginModule` whom inherits the `IModule` so I have this on my `LoginModule` class:

```
public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
{
        Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterLazySingleton(() => new ServiceEntityMapper(), typeof(IServiceEntityMapper));
        Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterLazySingleton(() => new LoginAPIService(), typeof(ILoginAPIService));
        Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterLazySingleton(() => new LoginManager(
        Locator.Current.GetService<IServiceEntityMapper>(),
        Locator.Current.GetService<ILoginAPIService>()), typeof(ILoginManager));
}
```

and I have this for my view model constructor:

```
 public LoginViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, ILoginManager loginManager = null) : base(navigationService)
 {
        LoginManager = loginManager ?? Locator.Current.GetService<ILoginManager>();
 }
```

In result, I get this exception whenever I navigate to the page

```
{System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve the signature of a virtual method
  at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00081] in <fe08c003e91342eb83df1ca48302ddbb>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].LazyInitValue () [0x00080] in <fe08c003e91342eb83df1ca48302ddbb>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x0003a] in <fe08c003e91342eb83df1ca48302ddbb>:0 
  at Splat.DependencyResolverMixins+<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<RegisterLazySingleton>b__0 () [0x00000] in <89c762f12a12451a8970372dc9921547>:0 
  at Splat.ModernDependencyResolver.GetService (System.Type serviceType, System.String contract) [0x00032] in <89c762f12a12451a8970372dc9921547>:0 
  at Splat.DependencyResolverMixins.GetService[T] (Splat.IDependencyResolver resolver, System.String contract)
```

Comment: We are introducing DryIOC with splat 7 due out in a couple weeks. You can use a myget package for a little while. See https://GitHub.com/reactiveui/splat and https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/installation/#development-packages

Comment: Hi @GlennWatson, I'll try to hit that, but that would mean nothing to me as Prism also have the DryIOC which I am trying to look for an alternative.

Comment: As far as I can see, Splat's just a service locator and no DI container. Also, which Bootstrapper / PrismApplication do you use? If you use one for DryIOC, it will try to resolve through DryIOC and fail if it's not registered...

Comment: @Haukinger Alright, yes DryIOC for it, seems like it cannot when resolving, I think this might be the case for it. I will try to mix and mix stuffs when I get back to my workplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen Splat is a Service Locator not an actual DI Container. That said you certainly are not limited to the base Prism implementations, as those are provided to make it simple to adopt and get started. What I might suggest in your case is to create your own implementation of IContainerExtension and inherit from PrismApplicationBase.

You can see it's really not that much extra work in your App class by looking either at the implementations for [Unity](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Unity.Forms/PrismApplication.cs) or [DryIoc](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.DryIoc.Forms/PrismApplication.cs)... there is a similar example using the [Grace DI Container](https://github.com/dansiegel/PrismGraceDemo). Keep in mind that a couple of new API's have been added since the last preview, with a proposed breaking change to make IContainerRegistry have a fluent API.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the best option if I would try to create my own implementation rather than combining both of them. Thanks.